# Same view appears when selecting menu item from navigation view after sliding through tablayout in xamarin android native

Tags: android, android-fragments, mobile, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

I have only been working with Xamarin android (native) for the first time (around a week) and I have taking code from here and there to see how it work, but I'm kind of stuck at the moment.

I have a navigation view with a tablayout. The navigation view fragments are manage by a SupportFragmentManager, which I later pass to  a viewpager to add some other fragments into my tablayout.

My problem occur once I select for the second time an menu item from the navigation panel. If I switch from for example, MenuItem_1 to MenuItem_2, the layout of MenuItem_2 is the same that I just saw in Menu_Item1, but the tabs titles change and the toolbar title and color also change, my only problem is that after picking one MenuItem the rest will show the same content as the first.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using MyApp.Fragments;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Content;
using TabIt
using MyApp.Fragments.Tabs;
using Android.Support.V4.App;

namespace MyApp
{
    //[Activity(ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [Activity(ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait, MainLauncher = false, LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon ="@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        int oldPosition = -1;
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView;
        IMenuItem previousItem;        
        ImageView navMenuImg;
        TabLayout tabLayout;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.drawer_layout);

            var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);

            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                 SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                 SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }

            drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_black);
            navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);            
            navMenuImg = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.nav_image);

            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (previousItem != null)
                    previousItem.SetChecked(false);

                navigationView.SetCheckedItem(e.MenuItem.ItemId);

                previousItem = e.MenuItem;

                if (toolbar != null)
                {
                    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);                    
                }
                switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
                {
                    case Resource.Id.nav_home:                        
                        ListItemClicked(0);

                        break;
                    case Resource.Id.nav_item1:
                        ListItemClicked(0);
                        toolbar.Title = "MenuItem1";
                        break;
                    case Resource.Id.nav_item2:
                        ListItemClicked(1);
                        toolbar.Title = "MenuItem2";
                        break;                   
                    case Resource.Id.nav_loginItem:
                        if (toolbar != null)
                        {
                            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                            SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                        ListItemClicked(2);
                        break;
                }

                drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            };

            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                navigationView.SetCheckedItem(Resource.Id.nav_MenuItem1);
                ListItemClicked(0);
            }
        }

        private void ListItemClicked(int position)
        {            
            if (position == oldPosition)
                return;

            oldPosition = position;

            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] fragArray = null;
            string[] titles = null;
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:
                    fragment = Fragment1.NewInstance();  
                    break;
                    fragArray = new Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[]
                    {
                        new TabFragment1(),
                        new TabFragment2(),
                        new TabFragment3()
                    };

                    titles = new string[]{"Item1Tab1","Item1Tab2","Item1Tab3" };

                    FnInitTabLayout(fragArray, titles);

                case 1:
                    fragment = Fragment2.NewInstance();
                    fragArray = new Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[]
                    {
                        new TabFragment1(),
                        new TabFragment2(),
                        new TabFragment3()
                    };

                    titles = new string[]{"Item2Tab1","Item2Tab2" };

                    FnInitTabLayout(fragArray, titles);
                    break;


               case 2:
                    fragment = LoginFragment.NewInstance();
                    break;
            }

            SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
                .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
                .Commit();
        }



        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Android.Resource.Id.MenuItem1:
                    drawerLayout.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
                    return true;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        void FnInitTabLayout(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment[] tabs, string[] fragTitles)
        {
            tabLayout.SetTabTextColors(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue, Android.Graphics.Color.White);

            var fragments = tabs;
            var titles = CharSequence.ArrayFromStringArray(fragTitles);
            var viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);

            viewPager.Adapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, fragments, titles);

            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);         

        }            
    }
}
```

My main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"-->

<!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>        

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my VievPager Adapter

```
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Java.Lang;

namespace TabIt
{
    public class TabsFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        private readonly Fragment[] fragments;

        private readonly ICharSequence[] titles;

        public TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment[] fragments, ICharSequence[] titles) : base(fm)
        {
            this.fragments = fragments;
            this.titles = titles;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return fragments.Length;
            }
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fragments[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            return titles[position];
        }
    }
}
```

I have  try to use the .Dispose() in almost every resource that I called in my main activity. I also did a quick watch on the tabLayout to see how many tabs it has and the count is correct. The problem is just the visualization. Like I mention, once I select a MenuItem from the Navigation menu, it does not matter if I change to another MenuItem I see the same content.

Can someone point me in the right direction? or at least take a look if something does not make sense?

Thank you as always in advance.

Comment: Just an observation 
case Resource.Id.nav_home: 
ListItemClicked(0);
Is a typo, I just forgot to erase it when I was adding the code. Sorry!

Comment: I also tried doing tabLayout.RemoveAllViews() and RemoveaAllTabs(), to generate them again, but didn't work either.